# perl + sed + remove lines that start with "#"

Tags: linux, solaris, perl, shell-scripting, sed

please advice

I have linux and solaris machines, and I need command that work on both OS

I use the following perl line in order to remove all lines that start with "#"
why perl command not work ,

remark - need to support also lines that start with space or TAB and then "#"

```
 perl -i -pe 'next if /^ *#/' file
```

.

```
   more file


   # aa a
       #  bbb 

      #xxx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will work on linux maybe also on solaris

```
sed -e '/^\s*#/d' file
```

**EDIT**: If \s is not supported maybe this will work...

```
sed -e '/^[ \t]*#/d' file
```

To do that in file just add `-i` to the command

If you don't want consecutive multiple  blank lines in the result, just pipe it through `uniq`

Comment: not work if before "#" I have space or TAB

Comment: you're sure? it does for me...
On which OS does it not work, only solaris?